# How to send request for this Soap Header in ios using ObjC?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am new in iPhone Development and want to get answer to send request for this soap header with user name ,password and company id,..

I have searched a lot of Tutorials, but nothing helped me.

Thanks in Advance.

Soap Code is:

```
<soap:Header>
<AuthenticationData xmlns="http://www.harikishan.com/">  //www.harikishan.com used as an example of website to which i need to send request
  <CompanyId>string</CompanyId>
  <UserName>string</UserName>
  <Password>string</Password>
</AuthenticationData>
</soap:Header>
```

Comment: This is not good question to ask. You should try something first and when you face problem than come with your problem. http://highoncoding.com/Articles/809_Consuming__NET_Web_Services_in_an_iOS_Application.aspx, http://www.macresearch.org/interacting-soap-based-web-services-cocoa-part-2, http://www.makebetterthings.com/iphone/call-soap-web-service-from-iphone/. http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: @CRDave,,,i did alot of research in this context,,but from now,,i will  put more effort before asking anything others,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to make a nnstring with you soap body

create 3 string for companyID, userName, password

```
NSString * soapBody  = [NSString stringWithFormat @"<soap:Header>"
"<AuthenticationData xmlns=\"http://www.harikishan.com/\">
  "<CompanyId>%@</CompanyId>"
  "<UserName>%@</UserName>"
  "<Password>%@</Password>"
  "</AuthenticationData>"
  "</soap:Header>", companyID, userName, password];
```

then add you `NSMutableURLRequest * request`

Comment: It would be better if you had a seperate class to make soaprequesthandler & soapresponsehandler.

Comment: @LalithB you right but that is not the question.

Comment: You need to XML encode those values.

Answer (score 1):

In general you will want to construct the XML payload, making sure to XML-encode any strings you insert, and post it to the server using `NSURLRequest`. You can then receive the response and handle that appropriately